# Have I evaluated this question correctly$?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification

> If $y=f(e^{-x})$ and $f'(x)=\ln x$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x=\ln2$ is

My work:

I calculated $f(x)=x\ln x-x+C$

Now, $y=f(e^{-x})=e^{-x}\cdot\ln(e^{-x})-e^{-x}+C=-e^{-x}\cdot x-e^{-x}+C$

Then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-x}\cdot x$$
Now put $x=\ln2$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=\ln2}=e^{-\ln2}\cdot\ln2$$

Now let $e^{-\ln2}=a$$\implies$

$$\ln(e^{-\ln2})=\ln a$$or$$\ln2^{-1}=\ln a$$ or
$$a=e^{-\ln2}=\frac12$$ Now doing $e^{-x}\cdot x=\frac{\ln2}{2}$

But the correct answer given is $\ln\sqrt{2}$

Where did I go wrong$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh you are all but done! Remember, $\frac{a}{b}\cdot \ln x=\ln x^{a/b}.$

Comment: @PCeltide oh damn!! How can I miss that!!! Thanks.

Comment: @AdamRubinson $y=f(e^{-x})$ and not $f(x)$

Comment: $$\frac12\ln{(2)}=\ln({2^{1/2}})$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If $y=f(e^{-x})$ and $f'(x)=\ln x$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $x=\ln2$ is

Yes, you can solve it by using the method in your work. But I believe this problem is designed to promote the **chain rule** method.

For example, if the problem is changed to $f'(x)=\ln(1+e^{\sin(x)})$, then you can't integrate it to find $f(x)$, hence your method fails in this case. But chain rule method still works.

"Chain rule" method:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(e^{-x})\cdot(e^{-x})'=\ln(e^{-x})\cdot(-e^{-x})=xe^{-x}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}|_{x=\ln(2)}=\frac{1}2\ln(2)$$

Comment: Nice explanation